# EF4 - update [Table] set @p = 0 where 

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

While going through SQL profiler, I noticed the following query generated by EF4.

```
exec sp_executesql N'declare @p int
update [dbo].[User]
set @p = 0
where (([UserID] = @0) and ([RowVersion] = @1))
select [RowVersion]
from [dbo].[User]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [UserID] = @0',N'@0 int,@1 binary(8)',@0=1,@1=0x000000000042DDCD
```

I am not sure why EF4 generates this while I am actually not updating any columns of the User table in that UnitOfWork. Running this query updates the **RowVersion column (timestamp datatype)** which leads to OptimisticConcurrencyException in the next UnitOfWork.

A quick googling led me to this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/e2444f09-d6e1-4fdc-84d3-aaa28dc98fd8/), which confirms that others have also run into this scenario without finding a solution yet.

Would greatly appreciate any pointers.

**Edit:** A sample code to replicate the issue.

[image]

User and Session tables have a **foreign key** relationship. Also, in EF4 I have set the **"Concurrency Mode"** property of RowVersion columns of both entities to **Fixed**.

Below is a sample method to replicate the scenario.

```
 private static void UpdateSession()
    {
        using (var context = new TestEntities())
        {
            context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            var session = context.Users.Include("Sessions").First().Sessions.First();
            session.LastActivityTime = DateTime.Now;

            context.ApplyCurrentValues("Sessions", session);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I see from Sql profiler the following queries being genrated by EF4.

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Session]
set [LastActivityTime] = @0
where (([SessionID] = @1) and ([RowVersion] = @2))
select [RowVersion]
from [dbo].[Session]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [SessionID] = @1',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 int,@2 binary(8)',@0='2011-06-20 09:43:30.6919628',@1=1,@2=0x00000000000007D7
```

And the next query is weird.

```
    exec sp_executesql N'declare @p int
update [dbo].[User]
set @p = 0
where (([UserID] = @0) and ([RowVersion] = @1))
select [RowVersion]
from [dbo].[User]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [UserID] = @0',N'@0 int,@1 binary(8)',@0=1,@1=0x00000000000007D3
```

Comment: What is the state of your `User` entity before you call `SaveChanges`? Also did you change any relation pointing to the `User`?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - I checked the ObjectStateManager and the state of User entity is Unchanged before SaveChanges. And yes, I modified a few entities that are related to User entity and while calling SaveChanges the above sql gets generated in addition to the required/expected sqls.

Comment: And what about the relation? Did you change any relation with this particular user?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - I am afraid I don't get your question correctly. Do you mean if I changed any properties of the navigation properties of User entity? If so , yes I am doing that.

Comment: Just in case if you do not modify navigation properties is this strange update still present?

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - I checked now and when I don't modify the navigation property the above update statement is not generated.

Comment: So now we know when, but I think question for Why? is for ADO.NET team.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - Do you know what is the best way to post this question to the ADO.NET team?

Comment: Create small reproducible example and open it as a bug (or something else) in [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/). If you have MSDN subscription you can also use some support ticket.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - Thanks for your help. I will get in touch in MS to for their help.

Comment: Please share the response from MS once you get it or add link to ms connect bug once you open it.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - Sure thing. I will do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is still problem for you but here is the hotfix by MS http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624

Comment: The KB link explains the scenario. However you need to open a MSDN ticket to get the hotfix. I just got mine and installing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Found this link referenced on another forum and was able to obtain a download for the hotfix mentioned by Kris Ivanov.

http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2390624

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about EF4, but with 4.1 we turned off the rowversion/timestamp by setting it to concurrenttoken = false.

We did this because

1. It was a calculated field in our db
2. It should never be changed by the application (in our case)

Comment: And because of that it should be set to `true`. Otherwise you can delete the column from the database at all because you don't use it as supposed - to handle concurrency.

Comment: In my case, I have to have the ConcurrencyMode of Rowversion column set to Fixed in order for EF4 to check for optimistic concurrency issues during update/delete.