# DbUpdateConcurrencyException on Unchanged entity

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

It appears that I am getting a concurrency exception on entities that are not modified.  I am using Entity Framework 4.3.1, Code First, and this is happening in a WCF service.

To simplify my example, let's assume I have two entities.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BarKey { get; set; }
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }

    public Bar MyBar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{    
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string OtherValue { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

The user can only edit Foos through the application.  Bars can be viewed, but not edited.  Additionally, I use DTOs with the WCF service.  The typical applicaiton flow is as follows.

1. Client calls service method `GetFoo`.  This will retrieve Foo from the database and map it to a FooDto.  This will also retrieve the related Bar and map it to a BarDto.
2. Client updates FooDto
3. Client calls `SaveFoo` and passes in an updated FooDto.
   a. The service will re-retrieve the original Foo, using `context.Set<Foo>().Find(fooDto.Id)`, then copy the updated values from FooDto.
   b. Business logic runs, which may call `context.Set<Bar>().Find(foo.BarKey)`.  Values may be read from Bar, but it will not be updated.
   c. The service then calls `context.SaveChanged()`.

At this point I occassionally get a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.  In my error handling, if the exception is of type `DbUpdateException`, which is the base class of `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`, I loop through `ex.Entries` and log`entry.Entity.GetType()` and `entry.State`.

In my error log I have several entries that show the type is `Bar` and the state is `Unchanged`.  It is entirely possible that `Bar` could have been updated.  However, I do not care because `Bar` is unchanged.

Why am I getting this exception and how to keep it from happening?

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232185/ef4-update-table-set-p-0-where?lq=1